# URL Redirection and 1and1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, redirect, dns, appdomain

I've got an app up and running on Heroku.  I've purchased a top level .com domain from 1and1 (I have other sites there, so I thought that would make life easier).

When I attempted to redirect to my Heroku app, I was not allowed to modify the `CName` alias record like I have done for other sites - which were all subdomains.  I was given two options: Frame redirect or `HTTP` redirect, I've tried both.  The frame redirect doesn't seem to function at all - the page stays blank.  The `HTTP` redirect does actually get to my heroku site, but when it displays the address bar shows `myproject.herokuapp.com` instead of `mydomain.com`.

I've added both the `www.mydomain.com` and `mydomain.com` to my heroku domains.

Is there anyway to add a mask or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: [you can not set CNAME for top of your domain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/apex-domains).

Detailed answer: [Why can't a CNAME record be used at the apex (aka root) of a domain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain/613830#613830)

Some DNS providers might offer [workaround](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169056-CNAME-Flattening-RFC-compliant-support-for-CNAME-at-the-root) [hacks](http://blog.dnsimple.com/2011/11/introducing-alias-record/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @dusanbajic... I was able to discover shortly after posting that setting CNAME wasn't an option for a top domain.  I'm still not completely clear on how I might go about accomplishing this, maybe purchase another domain from a different provider?

Comment: Another domain would not make the difference. And it does not matter where you purchase the domain. The only thing you can try (that I am aware of) is mentioned [Cloudflare workaround](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169056-CNAME-Flattening-RFC-compliant-support-for-CNAME-at-the-root).

Comment: The work around was a little too much for me to digest...  I purchased another domain at DNS Simple, which I'd seen in a tutorial not too long ago.  They had one click heroku "add-on" which allowed me to accomplish the top level redirect I wanted in seconds.  I'll wait the required time, then transfer my original domain to DNS Simple.