# Pointing my Heroku app to a domain on 1and1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns

How can I point my app on Heroku to a domain name through 1and1 UK?

Normally I use reg 123 and can add a CNAME entry but this doesn't seem possible with 1and1 (unless setting up a subdomain? not sure if this is correct).

In a nutshell when accessing mydomain.co.uk I would like it to serve my Heroku application.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33026513/url-redirection-and-1and1/33027309#33027309

Comment: @DusanBajic Thanks for the comment, it seems 1and1 state to create a subdomain and then i can add a CNAME, have you done anything like this before ?

Comment: I am not familiar with 1and1, but generally, for something.example.co.uk you don't need subdomain, you just add a CNAME. For example.co.uk, it is not possible to add CNAME (unless DNS provider offers some custom workaround for that)

Comment: ok so i have a domain name of `mydomain.co.uk` and my heroku app is at `mydomain.herokuapp.com`.. How can i get `mydomain.co.uk` to render my heroku app ?

Comment: There is no easy answer. There are two approaches available to serve traffic from the root domain while preserving the ability of your provider to manage your apps’ IP addresses: using a DNS provider that supports CNAME-like functionality at the apex, and using subdomain redirection.
Both approaches are discussed in the custom domains article: [Configure an apex domain for your app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-root-domain)

Comment: yes, with reg 123 for example this is a simple process as they support CNAME like functionality..I have managed to render my heroku site by using a subdomain but not quite what i was looking for, ideally want to have my root domain in the address bar

Comment: I see no other solution except to switch to DNS provider that provides that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit late to the party but i'm currently trying to use my domain through 1&1 to connect to my pythonanywhere app.

As i currently understand it you register your domain so:

**domain.co.uk** but then you need to create a subdomain like:

**www.domain.co.uk**

Then you can go into your subdomain www.domain.co.uk and then edit dns settings, and select CNAME and enter the CNAME that is given for your app.

Also to note that you need to make sure your subdomain matches what you have in your app, so if you want **www.domain.co.uk** then your webapp needs to reflect this. If you create a subdomain called **site.domain.co.uk** then your webapp needs to be **site.domain.co.uk**

It definitely is not the most user-friendly site but i'm waiting for my changes to propagate and will hopefully work! If not i've seen other sites and will probably switch as godaddy looks more friendlier to setup.

Comment: The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.