# Naked domain on Google Sites New

Tags: redirect, dns, hosting, google-sites-2016

I've been messing with my DNS settings and can't figure out how to get this to work...

I have G Suite for `example.com`, with a (new) Google Sites app published and accepting `www.example.com`. I have a CNAME in my DNS pointing `www` to Google, so `http://www.example.com/` and `https://www.example.com/` both work, with the `http` one doing a 301 to the `https` version, which is exactly what I want.

In my DNS (at GoDaddy), I have the base domain redirecting to `https://www.example.com` - so requests to `http://example.com` get forwarded properly.

The one leftover is `https://example.com/` - that one does not redirect because GoDaddy doesn't support it (I'd assume all hosting companies would be the same), but I want it to redirect like the others.

The only way I can think of is to have a live hosting account somewhere else, for `https://example.com/`, and have that redirect the browser over to `www`. I could do that with a static hosting (like Firebase) and use javascript, or app hosting with something like ASP.NET, and redirect directly in the response.

Is there an easier way, without using a separate hosting product?

(This might be a better question for ServerFault, but I figure I'd start here)

Comment: Probably the easiest way would be to switch to DNS provider that supports (non-standard) CNAMe at zone apex (zone root). https://stackoverflow.com/a/33027309/1145196

Comment: Trying over at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/896378/naked-domain-on-google-sites-new)

Answer (score 0):

Since even in the G Suite console address mapping is [supported only by HTTP and not HTTPS](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2518373), I only see one way - you can use Cloudflare for this.

This is a proven solution, I use it myself. This works because Cloudflare is effectively able to "see" your HTTPS traffic.

1. You change the NS servers for your domain to the NS servers that are assigned to your Cloudflare account.
2. Re-create all DNS records in Cloudflare.
3. Use this [small hack](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/redirect-example-com-to-www-example-com/78348).

However, I recommend using `301` response code for such a redirect, not `302`.