# DNS: forward root domain to www... when there are other DNS subdomains

Tags: dns, cname

I currently have a DNS setup where all content and applications are hosted on the same cloud server - example.com.

The presentation website is on example.com, www is forwarded to example.com with a CNAME and then various internal apps, eg app.example.com, are also forwarded with CNAME records to example.com. NGINX running on my server takes it from there, routing subdomains to the different apps.

I'd like to host the presentational website on an external service, and I'm confused about how to update my DNS config - specifically what to do with my A record.

I'm ok with creating a CNAME for www that will forward www.example.com to my external hosting service. But example.com is still pointing to my own server... and if I have understood correctly, if I forward example.com to www.example.com, then all my apps at eg app.example.com will break.

What are my options for handling this ?

My idea (from searching around) is that if I want example.com to point to an external service, then I should

1) create a new domain api-example.com whose A record points to a server where all my apps are hosted

2) make CNAME records for all my app subdomains on example.com which point to api-example.com

3) forward example.com to www.example.com, and forward www.example.com to the external service.

Will this configuration work ? Is there a simpler way to get the same result ?

Answer (score 1):

Your plan is fine, except for maybe one thing: generally, you can't have a `CNAME` record for the root (apex) of your domain. This means that your external presentation website hosting will have to provide an IP address, and you will create an `A` record that will point `example.com` to that address. Then you can have a `CNAME` record simply aliasing `www.example.com` to `example.com`.

Also make sure that you leave enough time between the steps, to make sure that all DNS TTLs expired so you don't encounter DNS caching issues.

For explanation (and possible workarounds) for domain apex CNAMEing issue, look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/33027309/1145196

Comment: OK so you would rather have A record pointing to external hosting service and CNAME pointing to example.com, as opposed to forwarding example.com to www.example.com and then CNAME www.example.com to external hosting service ?

Comment: In this article they argue the opposite: https://www.netlify.com/blog/2017/02/28/to-www-or-not-www/

Comment: That article is correct (but does not argue the opposite), the choice depends on whether your hosting provider will give you the IP address or some DNS name to which you will point your domain. Also, your use of term "forward" is either unusual/wrong or I misunderstood what you want to achieve ("forward" usually means "respond with 3XX redirect and the new Location, which also causes the change of address in client's browser address bar).

Comment: How about if I wanted to point "beta.example.com" subdomain to something that's hosted on a really long subdomain (like beta.ibm.cloud.xyz.com), would CNAME work?

Perhaps ALIAS is a better fit I wonder.

Comment: CNAME should do, but be keep in mind that usually the service running on server side also need to be aware/prepared to accept requests with "beta.example.com" host header